# Excel Nested IF AND formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't tell why I'm getting an error with the below formula:

```
=IF(AND(AL=AM, AK=TRUE), "Unchanged, " ", IF(AND(AL>AM, AK=TRUE), "Downgrade", " ", IF(AND(AL<AM, AK=TRUE), "Upgrade, " ")))
```

Columns AL and AM contain values 0-4. Column AK contains True/false. If the conditions are met I want to insert the text string. If they are not met, I want to insert the single space to leave the cell blank.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the nested IFs in the False of the previous:

```
=IF(AND(AL1=AM1, AK1), "Unchanged", IF(AND(AL1>AM1, AK1), "Downgrade", IF(AND(AL1<AM1, AK), "Upgrade", " ")))
```

Another method with out the AND():

```
IF(AK1,IF(L1=AM1,"Unchanged",IF(L1>AM1,"Downgrade",IF(L1<AM1,"Upgrade",""))),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `" "` after each of the text strings. The formula wasn't working because you were trying to define 4 parameters in each if statement. removing the `," "` should fix this.

```
=IF(AND(AL=AM, AK=TRUE), "Unchanged, IF(AND(AL>AM, AK=TRUE), "Downgrade", IF(AND(AL<AM, AK=TRUE), "Upgrade, " ")))
```